# Run ipython notebook by double-clicking and without keeping the terminal open (Ubuntu 20)

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I used to use [nbopen](https://github.com/takluyver/nbopen) in Ubuntu 16 to open `ipython` notebooks. It was integrated with unity GUI and I could just double-click on a notebook in a file manager and that would open the notebook in a browser. Conveniently, in Ubuntu 16 there was no terminal hanging in the background. After upgrading to Ubuntu 20 I can still use `nbopen` to open `ipython` notebooks by double-clicking, but the associated terminal is present. I do no use it and I would like to get rid of it. Is there a solution within `nbopen` or possibly some other?